# do xsd datatypes for literals have subclasses?

Tags: xsd, sparql, rdf, owl, graphdb

I'm trying to set up some lightweight, on-demand data validation outside of any reasoning system or triple-store provided load-time validation.  I'm using GraphDB 8.3.

Let's say I load the following triples, using the Ontology of Biomedical Investigations (OBI), http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/obi.owl:

```
PREFIX : <http://example.com/>
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
insert data {
    graph :data
    {
        :measurement1 a <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000032> ;
            <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000004> "100.1"^^xsd:double .
        :measurement2 a <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000032> ;
            <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000004> "100"^^xsd:int .
    }
}
```

That says that `:measurement1` and `:measurement2` have measurement values.  The range of `<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000004>` is `xsd:double`.  I know that I can check for datatypes that aren't exactly the same as the specified range with something like the query below.

As you can see in the comments embedded in my query, I'd like to say that that `:measurement2`'s value of `"100"^^xsd:int` is acceptable because all integers are contained within the set of double-precision floating point numbers.  (Right?)

**Is there an existing ontology that says that `xsd:int` is a sub-something of `xsd:double`?**

```
PREFIX : <http://example.com/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX obo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
# loaded obi into http://example.com/ontology
select distinct ?stype ?p ?ptype ?propdom ?proprange ?otype ?odatatype where {
    {
        graph :data
        {
            ?s ?p ?o .
            bind (datatype(?o) as ?odatatype)
        }
        optional {
            graph <http://example.com/ontology> {
                values ?ptype {
                    owl:ObjectProperty owl:DatatypeProperty
                }
                ?p a ?ptype
            }
        }   
        optional {
            ?o a ?otype
        }   
        optional {
            ?s a ?stype
        }   
        optional {
            {
                graph <http://example.com/ontology> {
                    ?p rdfs:domain ?propdom
                }
            }   
        }
        optional {
            {
                graph <http://example.com/ontology> {
                    ?p rdfs:range ?proprange
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    minus
    {
        ?s rdf:type ?o 
    }
    #       minus
    #    {
    #        ?odatatype rdfs:subClassOf+ ?proprange
    #    }
    filter ( ?odatatype != ?proprange )
}
```

Comment: [Long story](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-xsch-datatypes/)...

Answer (score 3):

XSD datatypes do not have subclasses. There are derived types: `xsd:int` is a derived type of `xsd:integer`; it is an XSD-defined feature.

`xsd:int` *not* a derived type of `xsd:double`.

What is important in datatypes is the value : `"100"^^xsd:int` and `"100"^^xsd:double` are the same value.  SHACL can express this.

See "Atomic Types" in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel-3/#types-hierarchy

Comment: << the value : `"100"^^xsd:int` and `"100"^^xsd:double` are the same value. SHACL can express this. >>  Well, this is kind of true, and false, according to the standard. This is a very bizarre fact of the XSD standard. The value spaces of `xsd:int` and `xsd:double` are disjoint, which means that whatever value `"100"^^xsd:int` denotes, it ought to be different from the value that `"100"^^xsd:double` denotes. However, the description of the value space of `xsd:int` and that of `xsd:double` suggest that they both contain numbers, as expected (that is, with the example, the number one hundred).

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions:

> all integers are contained within the set of double-precision floating point numbers. (Right?)

Wrong! As you say, `xsd:double` contains the set of double-precision floating point numbers, which does not contain numbers like the Graham number and other big integers.

> **Is there an existing ontology that says that `xsd:int` is a sub-something of `xsd:double`?**

If there is (I doubt there is), it's inconsistent with the spec of XSDs (see comment above).

To this, I should add the fact that XSD defines the value space of `xsd:decimal` as disjoint from that of `xsd:double`. This implies that the value space of `xsd:int` is  also disjoint from the one of `xsd:double`.

In general, I would recommend that you use `xsd:decimal` instead of `xsd:double` whenever possible. `xsd:double` suggests that it is never possible that the systems using your data or ontology are going to deal with better precisions or bigger numbers that those of `xsd:double`.

Answer (score 1):

If there are any such ontologies, they are most certainly custom user designed. I am not aware of any W3C standards to this effect. This (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes) diagram shows integer to be "derived" from decimal, though I am not sure to what extent this can be used as an ersatz subClassOf or anything of the sort.

Comment: Tip for creating useful answers, if you're going to quote something from the questioner, highlight the text then press the double-quote icon.  It will format the text so that it stands apart from your answer.  Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: I like that illustration.  In this case, maybe I will have to rely to the triplestore's load-time validator.  I'll post my experiences.

Answer (score 1):

To an extent, the specs do that. See for example: https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-xsch-datatypes/#sec-values

However, without any reasoner to do this, you'll have to replicate datatype reasoning on intervals and values common to multiple datatypes.

Comment: From a reasoner perspective (in the RDF, RDFS, OWL DL, OWL Full semantics), the specs do *not* do all that. The values of `xsd:int` and the values of `xsd:double` are disjoint. However, for RDF with support for XSD reasoning, or with OWL, it is the case that all `xsd:int`s are also `xsd:decimal`s, and in OWL (but not in RDF(S)), the `rdfs:subClassOf` relation between `xsd:int` and `xsd:decimal` is implied.